# RSS feed for favorite tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, bookmarks, rss

I noticed that every tag has its own RSS feed, it's a handy feature to follow particular subjects.

I wonder of there is something similar for own favorite tags: I know that I can individually subscribe to each one of them, but it's not very handy, because when you add or remove a particular tag from your favorites list, it won't update your feeds.

I've been unable to locate such a feature, is it present at all? And, if not, won't it be something useful to add in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this (even across sites) on http://stackexchange.com.

Open your profile, go to *Filtered Questions*, specify the rules (tags and sites), and save.

[image: Screenshot]

Open the newly created filter, and scroll to the bottom.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I was aware of this feature, but even there you have to manually add your tags rather than specify to include all your favorites (or at least I haven't figured out how to do it). Also, it just displays the results on the site rather than giving me a RSS, which can be used in any feed reader.

Comment: There's a feed, just scroll down (last sentence of the answer). But yes, it doesn't synchronize with your on-site favorite tags.

Comment: I totally missed the Feed icon, sorry.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-fully-open-source, something like http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/superuser/users/170331/favorites?body=true

Comment: It seems the tool I'm looking for. I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: It seems that it gives me my favourite questions (I mean the ones that I have starred) and not a feed for my favourite tags; I had a look in the settings, it seems that it can't do it, but I'm not so expert and I may be wrong.

Comment: Apparently it's not possible to determine – even when authenticated (your favorite tags are not public) – what your favorite and ignored tags are from the API.

Comment: Ok, at least now I know for sure that the feature isn't present. Thank you again.

Comment: Related MSO question: [Is there an API to get a user's favorite tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167234/is-there-an-api-to-get-a-users-favorite-tags). While there's a way to determine a user's *frequent* tags, that's something else. [Check it out here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-on-users).